# Can't save to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to save data to an csv file but i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Yr11 Computer Science\New Lessons\Lesson 26-27\song.py", line 13, in <module>
    csv_file = ([song, + ',' + artist + genre])
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'#
```

Heres the code:

```
import csv

print('*Welcome to Music*')
Choice = input('Do you want to *add* a song, print a *list* or *output* to a text file? ')
Choice = Choice.lower()

if Choice == 'add':
    song = input ("Please enter a song name: ")
    artist = input ("Please enter the Artist: ")
    genre = input ("Please enter the Genre: ")

    songs = open('songs.csv', 'a')
    csv_file = ([song, + ',' + artist + genre])
    songs.write(csv_file)
    database.close()

elif Choice == 'list':
    ()
```

Any help is appreciated Thank you

Comment: Hi! just remove the comma after `song` in the line: `csv_file = ([song, + ',' + artist + genre])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is only about the error message `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`. it is from the line

```
csv_file = ([song, + ',' + artist + genre])
```

and means that python can not make sense of `+ ','`. if you remove that first `+` you get rid of that particular error message. there may be more though....

python will then complain because you try to use a `list` as filename. maybe you wanted

```
csv_file = song + ',' + artist + genre
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on what the others have proposed and based on what I think you would need, I think you should have this code for the append:

```
with open("songs.csv", "a") as fa:
    line = song + "," + artist + "," + genre + "\n"
    fa.write(line)
```

This ensures the file object is closed after the append operation and also newer lines will be appended below the earlier line making the generated CSV structured.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't need a comma after `song`:

```
csv_file = ([song, + ',' + artist + genre])
```

Instead, try:

```
csv_file = ([song + ',' + artist + genre])
```

**Edit:** as suggested by @hiro protagonist - you can also simplify the whole line and write it without brackets.